# How to manually expire the token of login cognito -user in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using `aws-cognito` for authentication.

In my application, user admin can remove the role of other user. In that case if user is already login to the application/react,he still can access the page until token expire. and token can only expire if he logout.

Can we manually expire the session of any cognito user?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples-signout-user

Comment: @oreoluwa , in this mention link we have need cognitoUser, which is actually from the current session. but in my case as admin is removing the role so the current session is of admin not the user who's role is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only need UserPoolId and ClientId. You can store these values to use it when you want to log out your user. It shouldn't matter whether the role is removed by admin since your paramaters is not dependent on the user's role.

```
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId: '_', // Userpool id
    ClientId: '_' // Client app id you can find in your userpool "General settings" -> "App clients"
};
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
if (cognitoUser != null) {
    cognitoUser.signOut();
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples-signout-user

Comment: while using like this, it returns signOut() as undefined. Could you please help on it.